# "Ensuring Proper Display and Resizing of Videos and Images in React Native"

Tags: reactjs, native, react-native-video, react-native-fast-image

How can I ensure that videos and images are displayed properly in React Native, regardless of their orientation? Specifically, how can I make sure that landscape videos are displayed as portrait and that both images and videos are resized appropriately?

using react native video library for showing videos and fast image library for images

```
postImage: {
    flex: 1,
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined,
    borderRadius: 5,
    resizeMode: "contain",
    aspectRatio: 1,
  },
  postImages: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
  },
  postImageContainer: {
    width: "100%",
    aspectRatio: 1,
    // padding: 3,
  },
  selectedImage: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  videoContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    width: width,
    // height: 400,
    alignSelf: "center",
  },
  ImageBackground: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: "cover",
    width: "100%",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
```

I tried these styles

Answer (score 0):

> How can I ensure that videos and images are displayed properly in React Native, regardless of their orientation?

You can use [Dimensions](https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions) to achieve this. Import `Dimensions` from React Native

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
```

To identify the current orientation and render the view accordingly

```
    /**
     * Returns true if the screen is in portrait mode
     */
    const isPortrait = () => {
        const dim = Dimensions.get('screen');
        return dim.height >= dim.width;
    };
     
    /**
     * Returns true of the screen is in landscape mode
     */
    const isLandscape = () => {
        const dim = Dimensions.get('screen');
        return dim.width >= dim.height;
    };
```